# Mostrar datos en consola

Tags: javascript

tengo una página de indicadores, como puedo mostrar los indicadores en consola, este es mi código.

```js
var indicadores = null;

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        indicadores = this.response.indicadores;
        //document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = this.response.horoscopo.escorpion.amor;
    }
};
   

xhttp.open("GET", "https://mindicador.cl/api", true);
xhttp.send();


console.log();
```

Comment: Probaste colocando el `console.log(indicadores)` debajo de la linea `indicadores = this.response.indicadores;`

Comment: Si, me sale undefined!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Si revisas [la documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange), verás que hay que buscar la propiedad `responseText` del objeto `xhttp` que estás creando. En tu caso sería entonces algo así: **`xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhttp.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };`** Si la respuesta es un JSON significa que luego debes conocer su estructura para saber cómo leer la información que éste trae.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(indicadores);
```

Puedes tratar con eso si lo que quieres es imprimir la variable que almacena los indicadores

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar datos en consola del navegador debes usar:

```
console.log(mi_variable);
```

en tu caso mostrarias el resultado de tu llamado por **XMLHttpRequest**:

```
xhttp.responseType = 'json';
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        indicadores = this.response;
            console.log(indicadores);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://mindicador.cl/api", true);
xhttp.send();
```

finalmente te quedaria algo asi:

[image: result_xhr]

finalmente para acceder a tus datos puedes hacerlo algo asi:

```
console.log(indicadores.autor);
//mindicador.cl
```

Espero te sirva de guia.

Comment: Listo, solucionado!

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué usas `this` y no el nombre del objeto que se creó que es `xhttp`.  La documentación no sugiere el uso de `this`.

Comment: Mira, lo encontré en esta documentación con this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp